# Drupal doesn't output list of children on custom module page

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I am on Drupal 7. I want to create a page that lists its children, the same way you see the list of links in 'admin/structure' (Blocks, Content types, Entity types ...).

I have modified child 1 and child 2. They aren't really important for this example.

on mymodule.module I have inside function mymodule_menu():

```
  $items['admin/mymodule'] = array(
    'title' => 'My module parent page',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_admin_page',
    'access callback' => 'mymodule_admin_list',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'file' => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
  );

  // Child 1
  $items['admin/mymodule/child1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Child 1',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_something_01', 1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'file' => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
  );

  // Child 2
  $items['admin/mymodule/child2'] = array(
    'title' => 'Child 2',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_something_02', 1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'file' => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
  );
```

Then, on mymodule.admin.inc, I have this function:

```
function mymodule_admin_page() {
  $item = menu_get_item();
  if ($content = system_admin_menu_block($item)) {
    $output = theme('mymodule_admin_list', array('content' => $content));        
    // This gets printed on the page
    drupal_set_message('This gets printed on the page');
  }
  else {
    $output = t('You do not have any administrative items.');
    // This doesn't get printed on the page because my base page has children.
    drupal_set_message('This doesnt get printed on the page because my base page has children.');
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Finally, according to documentation I have read, I should add a function like the one below:

```
function theme_mymodule_admin_list($variables) {

  $content = $variables['content'];
  $output = '';
  // This doesn't get printed on the page...
  drupal_set_message('this doesnt get printed... Why???');

  if ($content) {
    $output = '<dl class="node-type-list">';
    foreach ($content as $item) {
      $output .= '<dt>' . l($item['title'], $item['href'], $item['localized_options']) . '</dt>';
      $output .= '<dd>' . filter_xss_admin($item['description']) . '</dd>';
    }
    $output .= '</dl>';
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Check my drupal_set_message above. Messages on function mymodule_admin_page get printed, but messages on theme_mymodule_admin_list don't get printed... Actually, admin/mymodule responds as a page, but instead of displaying links to its children, it will display a blank page...

I must be missing something, but I really don't know what. Thank you!

========

## SOLUTION

I am posting the solution below. Thank you, Geoff, for your comment. It did the trick! I was missing one of the pieces in this puzzle, which was the mymodule_theme function.

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'mymodule_admin_list' => array(
      'variables' => array('content' => NULL),
      'file' => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: might seem like stupid questions, but is theme_mymodule_admin_list() in your active themes template.php and have you flushed the cache?

Comment: Hey! Not stupid at all, your hint made all the difference! I was missing one of the pieces in the puzzle. Please, add your comment as an answer and I will check it as approved. Thank you! I am adding a more complete solution into my own question.

Comment: what I wrote wasn't really a solution even if it got you thinking in the right direction, so you can add your own if you like.

Comment: Well, ok, but pointing the right direction was really an eye-opener. Thank you. If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it as solved. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution here would be to do what the admin pages do for those pages

```
$items['admin/somemodule'] = array(
 'title' => 'My Module Section',
 'description' => 'Manage My Module',
 'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
 'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
 'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
 'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
);
```